# RPi3 font issue running GNUplot

Tags: fonts, gnuplot, raspberry-pi3

Running GNUplot on my RPi which is fully updated.

This plot command (part of a larger GNUplot script) displays the Symbola Full Moon character:

```
"" u (myDate(1,2)):(strcol(3) eq "Full" ? yAverage : $3):((strcol(3) eq "Full") ? ("◯"):1/0) w labels left font "Symbola,28" offset -4,0,\
```

The GNUplot script runs perfectly in OSX 10.11 but on the Pi when run in Terminal it changes that Symbola character as shown here:

```
>"" u (myDate(1,2)):(strcol(3) eq "Full" ? yAverage : $3):((strcol(3) eq "Full") ? ("â¯"):1/0) w labels left font "moon-phases,28" offset -4,0,\
```

and inserts that circumflex a and hyphen in the GNUplot output.

I installed the Symbola .ttf file, did a fc-cache -fv to rebuild the cache and fc-list shows the Symbola font.

Is this a UTF-8 issue in Terminal? How do I find out if the Pi Terminal handles UTF-8?

Comment: If that code is in a gnuplot script, it shouldn't depend on your terminal's capabilities (if you run the script like `gnuplot script.gp`) Maybe it is enough do add `set encoding utf8` at the beginning of the script

Comment: @Christoph the `gnuplot script.gp`worked perfectly.